# Windows Universal App 8.1 C++ / Custom Class Property

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an application on windows phone. In the VS template project there is a class SampleDataSource which implements the application's data layer. In a similar class I have added a property (AccountData^ Account) with my own class's type and get the following error LNK2001. Can anyone help me?

```
[Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
public ref class AccountDataSource sealed
{
public:
    property Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<AccountMessage^>^ Messages
    {
         Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<AccountMessage^>^ get();
    }
    property AccountData^ Account
    {
         AccountData^ get();
    }
internal:
    AccountDataSource();
    static concurrency::task<AccountData^> GetAccount(Platform::String^ id);
private:
    AccountData^ _account;
    Platform::Collections::Vector<AccountMessage^>^ _messages;
    static AccountDataSource^ _accountDataSource;
};
```

Error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class WindowsUniversalApp::Data::AccountData ^ __cdecl WindowsUniversalApp::Data::AccountDataSource::Account::
[WindowsUniversalApp::Data::__IAccountDataSourcePublicNonVirtuals::Account]::get(void)" (?get@?QAccount@__IAccountDataSourcePublicNonVirtuals@Data@WindowsUniversalApp@@1AccountDataSource@34@U$AAAP$AAVAccountData@34@XZ)
   C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projects\Universal\WindowsUniversalApp\WindowsUniversalApp\WindowsUniversalApp.Windows\AccountDataSource.obj  WindowsUniversalApp.Windows
```

Thank you,

Comment: What the LNK2001 error says? Can you give error details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have said that `Messages` is a property with a getter, but you haven't defined the getter anywhere. You need a function body:

```
property longTypeName Messages { longTypeName get() { return _messages; } }
```

(or of course you can put it in the CPP file).

Comment: Yes, Peter. That was the error. Unimplemented getters! Thanks!